# Passing a ref as function parameter React Native

Tags: react-native, reference

In my current code, I use a ref to change my `TextInput` component style, in a function using `setNativeProps` method.

```
class RegisterScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            borderBottomStyle: '#f7f7f7'
        }
    }

    focusedInput = () => { 
        this.textInput.setNativeProps({
            style: { borderBottomColor: '#445AE3' }
        }) 
    }
    
    blurredInput = () => { 
        this.textInput.setNativeProps({
            style: { borderBottomColor: '#f7f7f7' }
        }) 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
               <View style={styles.form}>
                    <TextInput
                        ref={c => { this.textInput = c}} 
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        onFocus={this.focusedInput}
                        onBlur={this.blurredInput}
                        style={[styles.formInput, { borderBottomColor: this.state.borderBottomStyle }]}
                        placeholder={"Email"}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={[styles.formInput, { borderBottomColor: this.state.borderBottomStyle }]}
                        placeholder={"Password"}
                    />
               </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default RegisterScreen
```

It works well with my first `TextInput` but I'am looking for a way to do the same thing for the second one. I first thought to pass the ref to the `focusedInput` and `blurredInput` functions as a parameter, to specify the element to modify, but I am not so familiar with refs...

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to conditionally change UI of your text boxes based on focused or not.

You can just use one state to keep the currentlyFocused textInput name and conditionally change the UI of your textboxes based on currentlyFocused box.

I made a quick demo on sandbox. Look at below link.

[Demo Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-text-input-border-dc2ql)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, TextInput } from "react-native";

class RegisterScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      borderBottomStyle: "#f7f7f7",
      currentlyFocused: null
    };
  }

  focusedInput = () => {
    this.textInput.setNativeProps({
      style: { borderBottomColor: "#445AE3" }
    });
  };

  blurredInput = () => {
    this.textInput.setNativeProps({
      style: { borderBottomColor: "#f7f7f7" }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={{
              borderBottomColor:
                this.state.currentlyFocused === "email" ? "red" : "grey",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderWidth: this.state.currentlyFocused === "email" ? 3 : 0,
              height: 50,
              marginTop: 20
            }}
            onFocus={() => this.setState({ currentlyFocused: "email" })}
            onBlur={() => this.setState({ currentlyFocused: "" })}
            placeholder={"Email"}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={{
              borderBottomColor:
                this.state.currentlyFocused === "password" ? "red" : "grey",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderWidth: this.state.currentlyFocused === "password" ? 3 : 0,
              height: 50,
              marginTop: 20
            }}
            onFocus={() => this.setState({ currentlyFocused: "password" })}
            onBlur={() => this.setState({ currentlyFocused: "" })}
            placeholder={"Password"}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default RegisterScreen;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly. I've just modified the ternary condition on the borderWidth when false, to be sure to always have a bottom border.

I knew that it was possible to achieve that with some setState, but I was curious to learn more about refs in that case because it's really hard to find good doc about that.